# Pulling in different Git branch

Tags: git

Say I create a repo and it has one branch called master. If someone else forks the repo and pushes to a new branch B, what is the best way for me to pull in B locally without overwriting my local master branch? Do I switch to branch B locally and then pull in the changes? My guess is if I don't explicitly switch branches locally then if I pull in the changes from the remote branch B then I will overwrite my local master branch with B. What is the best option here?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do after you got the changes in your local repository?

Comment: You wouldn't *overwrite* master, you would create a new merge commit (if the merge isn't fast-forward) in your master branch.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `git fetch origin branchname` .
By doing a `git pull origin branchname` 
 you can merge the changes of both the branches. install a mergetool like kdiff3.
You can integrate the two, follow this [link](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1192/setup-git-on-windows-to-use-kdiff3-as-its-mergetool/)

Answer (score 2):

```
git fetch origin
git checkout --track origin/<remote_branch_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git fetch origin branchB` to get all commits from `branchB` without modifying your `master` or your working directory.

If you want to apply the changes to your `master`, you can merge them using `git merge FETCH_HEAD` while you are on your `master` branch. This creates a new commit with all the changes from `master` and from `branchB`. `FETCH_HEAD` is the last commit that was fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that when you write "[someone] pushes to a new branch B", you mean that they push to their fork repo, not to the original repo `origin`.

Rather than fetching `B` from origin, you need to fetch from their fork:

```
git fetch <url/to/their/fork/repo> B
```

You will get a copy of the commits in their branch `B`, and you can see the remote branch with `git branch -a`. You can `checkout` the remote branch to make your working files reflect branch `B`.

If you want, you can create a local branch at the same time you are fetching. The name of the created local branch comes after a `:` :

```
git fetch <url/to/their/fork/repo> B:B
```

Now instead of running `git checkout` on a rather long branch name, you can just `git checkout B`.

Remember that `pull` is just `fetch` + `merge`, and that `merge` happens with the branch that is currently checked out. Your guess is kind of correct in that if you run `git pull` while `master` is checked out, you will merge the content of the pulled branch into `master`. This is not really overwriting though, rather adding a commit to `master`.

---

If you are going to use their fork repo more times, you can add it as a remote:

```
git remote add their_fork <url/to/their/fork/repo>
```

After this you do not need to write their whole URL, you can use the remote name instead:

```
git fetch their_fork B:B
```